# What would be a good language/framework pair for learning Web development?

Tags: programming-languages

What would be a good language/framework pair for learning Web development? I know other people have asked this very same question (for example, [Learning Web Development-Choosing a Language and Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731685/learning-web-development-choosing-a-language-and-framework)), **however**, my case is a little different, since I have some additional constraints:

- The language the framework is written in must not be "opinionated" about the way I should do things. On the other hand, the framework being opinionated is not much of a problem, as I can always at some point <s>ditch</s> replace it <s>for</s> with another framework or even my own mini-framework.
- The framework must let me see how it works, aka, I must have access to the source code. (Which is not the same as the framework being open source. I just want to be able to *read* the source.)

Also, since my Web server is a Windows 7 Professional x64 machine with Apache 2.2 installed:

- The framework must provide convenient access to at least one database engine that can be installed on Windows 7 Professional x64.
- Deployment of my Web applications must be as easy as installing an Apache module, editing the httpd.conf file properly and restarting Apache.

Optionally, in decreasing order of priority:

- It is desirable that the language the framework is written in be dynamic.
- It is desirable that the framework provide convenient access to *any* SQL database that can be installed on Windows 7 Professional x64.
- It is desirable that the framework or a module/plugin compatible with the framework provide convenient access to a non-relational database that can be installed on Windows 7 Professional x64.

---

**EDIT:** Since my question has been labelled "subjective and argumentative" not only once but twice, I want to clarify some things:

- If the word "ditch" was too crude, my apologies. I already <s>ditched</s> replaced it.
- By specifying that the language not be "opinionated", my intention is to avoid having to ask "What is the recommendable/standard/approved/blessed/inherently-good way to do something?" in the future. I want to design my applications, desktop or Web, entirely on my own. If only to find out why some designs are not recommendable/standard/approved/blessed/inherently-good.
- By specifying that the framework let me study how it works, my intention is to avoid having to ask "Why subsystem X throws error Y when I try to do Z?". I want to find it out on my own. If only for education purposes.
- There is nothing else I can find that I think can potentially be interpreted as "subjective and argumentative". In particular, specifying an operating system and a Web server just means "I don't want to have to install other things than I already have installed on my PC". (Besides, Apache is pretty much *the* standard Web server.)
- Yeah, the question is open ended. This is because I am asking for *suggestions*. And, since I am a complete newbie to Web development, there would be no point (at least for me) in arguing your suggestions. Also notice, the question is *community wiki*.

Comment: You have a lot of requirements for someone who just wants to LEARN about web development...

Comment: Well, I learnt Win32 development by reading MFC's sources and trying to do what I could do with MFC, minus the crazy macros, minus the limitations (like menus not having icons), all by myself. I expect no less from a Web development framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smalltalk with Seaside would be the most fun. [One click image](http://www.seaside.st) can be downloaded, and the [book](http://book.seaside.st) is online.

1 Smalltalk insists that you organize your code in classes and methods, but is open to suggestions on how to do that. Seaside is an opinionated web framework, with a strong focus on DRY.

2 It is a Smalltalk, so all objects and sources are available and inspectable.

3 You can easily get started without a database. Larger scale persistence is done most easily by deploying on a [glass](http://glass.gemstone.com) object-oriented database (zero code needed). It runs in a VMWare image or on a linux or os-x machine. If you want to write code, you can use the GLORP ORM with SqueakDBX to connect to all databases supported by openDBX, or directly to PostgreSQL.

4 Does it have to be that difficult?

5 If it provides an ODBC adapter.

6 There are interfaces to various NoSQL databases.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to learn both a server-side and a client-side language.

For client-side development, I recommend:

JavaScript with the JQuery framework library http://www.jquery.com

For Server-side development, I recommend:

C# with the .NET framework library http://www.microsoft.com/express/windows/

Answer (score 1):

[PHP](http://www.php.net/) and [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) are pretty good for LEARNING, there are lots of examples, tutorials and help out there and CakePHP follows the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller).